# Prefix # to output except numbers from 0-100

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have some output from another program of the form

```
foo
10000
bar
20
baz
30
qux
50
...
```

This output needs to be converted so that the lines that do not contain numbers between 0 and 100 get prefixed with a `#` (via piping only):

```
#foo
#10000
#bar
20
#baz
30
#qux
50
...
```

How could this be achieved, using one of the standard Linux tools (prefereably sed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed` if 0..100 is exclusive (so `100` should not be preprended):

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{1,2\}$/! s/^/#/' INPUTFILE
```

*Update*: if the input can contain decimals too, you might want to use this version instead:

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{1,2\}\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?$/! s/^/#/' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: This will fail if decimal are used, not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: @Jotne could you please elaborate on how/on what input could it fail? As I see, 10 is a decimal and it will work properly.

Comment: I did mean number like this `30.234`. OP does not specify that number should not be integer, just between `0` and `100`

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '$0>99 {$0="#"$0}1'
#foo
#10000
#bar
20
#baz
30
#qux
50
```

To use with `pipe`

```
command | awk '$0>99 {$0="#"$0}1'
```

It will give `#` in front of all number larger than `100`